# PHP - Sort the merged & shuffled array with specific value as first array value

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, shuffle, array-merge

I have 3 `nested arrays` which I use `array_merge` to merge them, as well as `shuffle` to shuffle them.

These are my arrays:

```
$array_1 = [
    ['product_1_1', 300, 100],
    ['product_1_2', 300, 100],
    ['product_1_3', 300, 100],
    ['product_1_4', 300, 100],
    ['product_1_5', 300, 100],
];

$array_2 = [
    ['product_2_1', 300, 250],
    ['product_2_2', 300, 250],
    ['product_2_3', 300, 250],
    ['product_2_4', 300, 250],
    ['product_2_5', 300, 250],
];

$array_3 = [
    ['product_3_1', 300, 500],
    ['product_3_2', 300, 500],
    ['product_3_3', 300, 500],
    ['product_3_4', 300, 500],
    ['product_3_5', 300, 500],
];
```

What I want to achieve is after the `shuffle` is done, it **always** put one of the values in `$array_1` at first, so that the shuffled array always start with one of the values in `$array_1`.

Comment: Shuffle $array_1 first, then shift the first item from it. Combine the rest with your other arrays afterwards, shuffle that, and add the item you shifted off, at the beginning again …

Comment: thanks @CBroe appreciate your comment. I'll try that. I'm new to `PHP` you see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way. Pick a random index from array_1 and remove the element from the array. Then combine all, merge and shuffle, ending with array_unshift which will prepend the final array with our random array_1 value.

```
<?php

$array_1 = [
    ['product_1_1', 300, 100],
    ['product_1_2', 300, 100],
    ['product_1_3', 300, 100],
    ['product_1_4', 300, 100],
    ['product_1_5', 300, 100],
];

$array_2 = [
    ['product_2_1', 300, 250],
    ['product_2_2', 300, 250],
    ['product_2_3', 300, 250],
    ['product_2_4', 300, 250],
    ['product_2_5', 300, 250],
];

$array_3 = [
    ['product_3_1', 300, 500],
    ['product_3_2', 300, 500],
    ['product_3_3', 300, 500],
    ['product_3_4', 300, 500],
    ['product_3_5', 300, 500],
];

$first = rand(0, floor(count($array_1))); 
$firstItem = $array_1[$first];
unset($array_1[$first]);
 
$merged = array_merge($array_1, $array_2, $array_3);
shuffle($merged);
array_unshift($merged, $firstItem);
```